# Drupal - errors on image uploads

Tags: php, drupal, upload, drupal-7, gd

I just moved a drupal site to a new server running Debian 7.5 stable (Wheezy) (64bits).

I now get errors when trying to upload images. They can be different:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Unsupported marker type 0xf8
```

or

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 145 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd0
```

or

```
Corrupt JPEG data: bad Huffman code
```

I have no clue what the issue can be. If it comes from Drupal, from PHP, from GD, or from Debian itself.... Any help would be very very much appreciated!

Comment: This does not seem related to Drupal. Try this. create a simple PHP script with a form with file upload field and try to upload an image, if you get the same error, you will need to check the system

Comment: Just did the test as you advised with a simple php script. It all works fine, no errors at all :/

Comment: Well.. Something weird happened. It seems to work now... really strange...

Comment: Check apache & Drupal logs for more details